# Moment map in general

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-algebras, group-actions, vector-fields

Let the Lie group $G$ act on the smooth manifold $X$ with the map $(g,x)\to gx$. In any point $x\in X$, the differential of this map induces a linear map:
$$
 \mu:T_e G \to T_xX\;,
$$
and globally, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$, a map $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{X}(X)$. (If I'm not mistaken, this should be even a Lie algebra homomorphism.)
If $X$ is symplectic and $G$ acts by symplectomorphisms, this map is known as the *moment map*, because it gives the momenta of physics.

> What is its name in general? And where can I find information about it?

Thanks.

**EDIT (see Mike Miller's comment below)**:

Note that a linear map $\mathfrak{g}\to T_xX$ is (basically) the same as an element of $\mathfrak{g}^*\otimes T_xX$, which is (basically) the same as a map $T^*_xX\to \mathfrak{g}^*$.

In the case of symplectic manifolds, the map $m:T^*_xX\to \mathfrak{g}^*$ is composed with the symplectic gradient $gr:f\mapsto(df)^\sharp$, to give:
$$
gr^*m: X\to T^*X\to \mathfrak{g}^*\;,
$$
and *this* is called the moment map (Souriau, "Structure of Dynamical Systems"). But this works only for symplectic manifolds, because in general there is no canonical way to map functions $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{X}(X)$ into maps $X\to \mathfrak{g}^*$. 
The first one is just the differential of the group action, and so it is naturally defined in general.

Comment: 1) You mean $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak X(M)$, the latter being the space of vector fields, yes? Otherwise I don't know what you mean. 2) As far as I know, the moment map is a map $M \to \mathfrak g^*$, and only exists for Hamiltonian actions.

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh yes, corrected.

Comment: Can you address 2), maybe with a reference to somewhere this is called the moment map?

Comment: @MikeMiller yes, edited.

Comment: Great, thanks. I don't see people talking much about the Lie algebra homomorphism you mention. The only place I've seen it is in Ch 1 of Kobayashi-Nomizu. I don't think it'll say anything satisfying there but it might be worth a look.

Comment: @MikeMiller I'll look, thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything out?

Comment: @MikeMiller Nope. It's just referred to as "the differential of the group action", or sometimes as "the action of the Lie algebra on $M$", everywhere I look. Maybe that's all that there is to it. And I can't find anything either about its interpretation as $\mathfrak{g}^*$-valued vector field...but well that's subjective, maybe it helps only my own intuition.